# Wifi adapter not found or recognized on 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Wi-Fi adapter Intel WM3945ABG. Though this info doesn't even appear in output when lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 is run. I have tried rfkill list all and there is no software or hardware block on Bluetooth but doesn't even mention Wi-Fi. When I press hardware switch airplane mode comes on.
Update: I ran the command: dmesg | grep iwl and it said [619.465539] iwl3945: hw_scan is disabled. Anyone know what that means and how to fix it?

Comment: @GAD3R It should be `iwl3945`. Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/808182 Try the same and also with `disable_hw_scan=1`

Comment: Tried disable_hw_scan=0 and 1 and each time it said no such file or directory exists.

Comment: Also tried sudo update-pciids and nothing happens

Comment: @MeenaDev Did you try the commands in the linked answer? It sounds you tried something else.

Comment: I tried the download command in the link and it says name or service not known over and over and unable to resolve host address .

Comment: @MeenaDev The commands I meant are `sudo rmmod -f iwl3945; sudo modprobe iwl3945 disable_hw_scan=0` or `sudo rmmod -f iwl3945; sudo modprobe iwl3945 disable_hw_scan=1`.